# Как в PHP строку разбить на массив

Tags: php, массивы, регулярные-выражения

Как разбить строку:

```
|ele1||ele2||ele3||ele4||var5||nubmr|
```

На массив вида:

```
[0]=>ele1
[1]=>ele2
[2]=>ele3
[3]=>ele4
[4]=>var5
[5]=>nubmr
```

как вариант хотелось бы удалить первый и последний элемент строки с помощью `preg_replace` (не знаю как если знаете то подскажите)
а потом разбить через explode

Comment: Спасибо! Работает)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.

```
preg_replace('/^\|(.+)\|$/','$1','|ele1||ele2||ele3||ele4||var5||nubmr|');
```

Answer (score 3):

Проще.

```
explode('||', "ele1||ele2||ele3||ele4||var5||nub")
```

И потом удалить из массива

Comment: Можно просто заранее подготовить строку.  

    explode ("||", substr($text, 1, strlen($text)-1));